# Wait for multiple elements to become invisible Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using this code to check for invisibility:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(<some xpath>)));
```

This works perfectly if there is only ***one*** element corresponding to the xpath in the webpage.

I have ***three*** in the webpage which I am trying to write a script for, and I need selenium to wait for all three.

Note: I am not using absolute xpath.

Comment: Do you have 3 webelement with the same xpath ?

Comment: Yes, wasn't that clear from the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated` check for the first element. In your case you could write your own implementation of `ExpectedCondition` where you have to check if the object is displayed for each of the element which is found.

For Example (not tested) :

```
private static void waitTillAllVisible(WebDriverWait wait, By locator) {

    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {

            Iterator<WebElement> eleIterator = driver.findElements(locator).iterator();
            while (eleIterator.hasNext()) {
                boolean displayed = false;
                try {
                    displayed = eleIterator.next().isDisplayed();
                }
                catch (NoSuchElementException | StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                    // 'No such element' or 'Stale' means element is not available on the page
                    displayed = false;
                }
                if (displayed) {
                    // return false even if one of them is displayed.
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // this means all are not displayed/invisible
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks like it might work, but am having trouble debugging. Please fix "*Does not have type parameter*" and "*method does not override from super class*" errors

Comment: Compiles fine on my machine. Which version of java and selenium are you using ?

Comment: Java 1.8, Selenium 3.0.1

Comment: Ok I just imported the ExpectedCondition. My bad

Comment: Took me a while to test it. Works pretty well thanks. Although I needed to introduce a bit of a sleep before the webpage loaded for your code to work properly.